# Grails routing plugin - unable to parse email body after parsing email from gmail inbox

Tags: grails, email

We are using `grails routing plugin` with `grails - 2.1.1` to consume email from our gmail inbox.

We were following this document [from haki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/04/use-apache-camel-plugin-in-grails.html)  to `consume email` and its associated `attachments`. Everything was working as expected.

```
exchange.in.headers.from - was giving us email sent from email Id.
exchange.in.headers.subject - was giving us subject of the email.
```

But now we want to parse the `body` of email as well. When we try to print

```
exchange.in.body
```

We get

```
javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@b6881e
```

as output.

Is there a way to parse whole body of the email in string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart object. By [definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html), you can try:

```
def body = exchange.in.body
for(int i=0; i<body.getCount(); i++){
    def part = body.getBodyPart(i)
    println 'content ' + i + ' : ' + new String(part.content)
}
```

Or, you can try to explore the body using properties:

```
exchange.in.body.properties.each{p->
    println p
}
```

I'd like to recommend the 2nd approach, by Which you can find what is inside the object and the best way to deal with it.

Comment: gr8 :) thanx a lot Jinzhao

Comment: how can we fetch only the last reply of a email thread. Not the whole body.

Comment: Can you post a sample? I guess it's because the mail sender includes all the past thread in his mail. So you may have to split it with some dividing string.

Comment: yes, all the past threads are included in the mail. And each mail provider has there on way to do so. Like different html tags and different text to display the contents.

Comment: I mean the person who sent the mail included all the past thread, so that they became a part of the mail body. Therefore, you may have to divide the thread into parts manually. A real example would be helpful.